# サクラエディタの文字色変更について。

Tags: テキストファイル, サクラエディタ

サクラエディタである特定の文字を強調したいのでエクセルのように文字を範囲選択して色を変えることはできるのでしょうか。サクラエディタを閉じても色が残っている状態にしたいと思っています。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

一般にテキストファイルの中身は文字列でしかないので、そこに色の情報を含ませることはできません。何かしらマークアップの構文を作ってサクラエディタのプラグインで認識させ色をつけることはできるかもしれませんが、他のエディタで開いたとき意味不明になります。

そこで、テキスト (.txt) ではなく[リッチテキスト](https://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rich_Text_Format) (.rtf) として保存するならば、文字に色などの情報を追加することができます。リッチテキスト形式はサクラエディタだけでなく、Windows に標準でついているワードパッドや macOS のテキストエディット、あるいは Microsoft Office Word などでも開いて編集することができます。

Answer (score 0):

サクラだと、単語がほとんど限られるの前提ですが、シンタックスハイライト用の辞書を自力で作るのがてっとり速いかと。

もし本当に質問に書かれているようなイメージ...コロコロ変わるような単語に都度色付けするような機能が必要であれば...nekketsuuuさんの書かれているようにtext形式だとムリですね。
サクラでmarkdownとかプレビューしてくれると、選択肢に入れれるんですけどね...

他のテキストエディタであればmarkdownプレビューしてくれるものもありますけど...